# How to scale a layer in pixelated fashion in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, scale

How to scale a layer in pixelated fashion? I.e. each pixel of the image will grow to the block of pixels in the final scene without smoothing or blending (see picture below):

[image: Scaling in progress, from left to right]

**WORKAROUND**

To achieve desired effect you could use the *Draft* option quality of the layer:
`Layer > Quality > Draft`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I read your mind. What you are talking about called **Quality and Sampling**. You can find it in the timeline on your layer when "Switches" are activated:

[image: Look at the rad arrow]

Adjust it to pixelated view, and you will be able to reach your goal without any effects.

Comment: I believe comments don't accept images, but editing the answer can stay unnoticed by the topicstarter...

Comment: Then sorry. I am new here, and trying to do my best in finding solutions to other people problems. Will try to recognize that stuff in the future better.

Comment: But first answer is not wrong! The Mosaic effect can handle this task, for example, for vector graphic. Or when picture starting to pixalete no on the needed scale... It is tow different approaches to achieve the desired result for OP...

Answer (score 2):

It will scale like that, because every picture made of pixels <sub>(except vector graphics, but just don't use that)</sub>

You can force it with effect <kbd>Stylize</kbd> > <kbd>Mosaic</kbd>

Good luck!

Comment: I tried _Mosaic_ effect but it didn't help much (changed _Blocks_ keyframed option)

Comment: Why It didn't help? What was the difference between obtained results and the expected result? Sorry, I can not read minds.

Comment: When scaling it makes the image blurred on low _Block_ values and just like usual scaled at high _Block_ values. So maybe I need somehow relate these values with image width-height and scaling ratio?